# Is it possible to specify opening a URL with a specific browser in pure Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I know very little about coding, I'm afraid, and most of what I do know is on the front end, so my knowledge of Ruby is approximately nil. A while ago, though, I modified a plugin script for xbar as best I could because the default wasn't working--basically, the default script called for giving a URL in the dropdown menu when a Wanikani review showed up, but I couldn't find a way for that to happen so I instead did a janky but functional workaround where the plugin just checks for a review and if there is one it uses `system("open", "https://www.wanikani.com")` to open a window. That's all fine, it works okay even if it's a bit annoying.

That said, there are a number of Wanikani scripts that don't work properly on Safari, so I've been wondering whether I could get this plugin to open the url in Chrome instead when a review shows up, even though my system's default browser is Safari. Doing some poking around, it looked like there could be maybe some options if I used some other gems, but I've not had any luck getting anything external to work with this plugin...probably because I have no idea what I'm doing, but even so.

tl;dr Is there any way with just Ruby to specify a browser and use it to open a URL?

I'm a bit wary of showing the code just because, well, it's not mine, but noting the original code is by [Github user Nzebo](https://github.com/Nzebo) and I've only made a mess of it, the applicable section is here:

```
  # calculate the next time a review is available
  def calc_next_review_time
    next_review_time = Time.parse(@summary['data']['next_reviews_at']).localtime

    if next_review_time < Time.now.localtime
      system("open", "https://www.wanikani.com")
    else
      next_review_time.strftime(' %l %p')
    end
```

I very much apologize if this is a super silly question, or if it's...taboo to ask questions about modifying other people's code for personal use? (It hasn't been updated in four years, otherwise I would've put in a request or something, but...) Anyway, thank you for your time!

Comment: If this is macOS then you could use the `-a` switch to `open`: `system('open', '-a', 'Google Chrome', 'https://www.wanikani.com')`.

Comment: If you want a cross-platform compatible solution then use the [launchy gem](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy), there are examples in the readme of how to supply a list of browsers to try in decending order.